# Add row number and word count to end of lines in text file

Tags: python, file, row, word-count

I'm having trouble writing my row number (i) and word count (words) to the end of each line in the file I'm creating.

It should be something like below

cat

cat in

cat in the hat

becomes

cat 0 1

cat in 1 3

cat in the hat 2 7

Note: I can not use imported functions

```
def annotate(f_in):
    with open(f_in, 'r') as f:
        with open('annotated.txt', 'w') as f_out:
            words = 0
            for i, line in enumerate(f, start = 0):
                words += len(line.split(' '))
                print(line, i, words)
                f_out.write(line)
```

Comment: What exactly is happening that you don’t expect here? It seems like you are printing the output you want to the console but not doing the same when writing to the file. If it is coming out correctly on the console but not in the file than this should be the reason. If not, please explain exactly what is happening that shouldn’t be.

Comment: I think I might have been a bit unclear.

print(line, i, words) 
f_out.write(line) <-- I would want this to have the same output as the line above

In other words, I do not just want to print, I also want to have the f_out to be written as I have printed.

Comment: So it is as you say, it is not coming to the file. 
I know I need to change the 
f_out.write(line)
in some way to make it happen, but I do not know exactly how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by appending each line in the file to a 2d list and use the list index as the row number and the length of the embeded list as the number of words.

```
file = open("catinhat.txt", "r")

lines = []
for line in file: 
  stripped_line = line.strip() # strip the line of "\n"
  line_list = stripped_line.split() # make the line into a list of words
  lines.append(line_list) # make 2d list of each line

file.close()

totalWords = 0
for i in range(len(lines)):
    row = i
    noWordsInRow = len(lines[i])
    totalWords+=noWordsInRow
    print(row, totalWords)
```

The output of this is:

```
0 1
1 3
2 6
3 10
```

hope this is what you needed :)

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I have not been clear enough in my explanations. I will try to explain better :)

I still want the text to show, as I mentioned in the example above but that the output 
1) creates a new file (f_out)
2) the new file, f_out, has the same text as my f_in but with the row number and number of words in total after each line has been read.